# Can't change Navigation bar text font and color at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I’m trying to change the text font and color at the same time but unfortunately only one of them change. Please where would be my issue?

```
    self.title = "Hello Members"

    if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Body", size: 15) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orangeColor()]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var attributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 30)!
    ]

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Comment: That works I whink my issue is that; I'm setting the `titleTextAttributes ` twice. I will accept in 10 min